# How do i update MongoDB document Using conditional operator in a spring mongo

Tags: spring, mongodb

I want to re-write the below Mongodb query in Spring data Mongo.

```
db.paymentRequest.update(
    { _id: "1234" },
    [
        {
            $set: {
                "status": {$cond: [{$ne: ["$status", "COMPLETED"]}, "toprocess", "$status"]},
                "name": "shell5"
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about the conditional operator

Comment: You can use [Spring Data MongoTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo-template) API to update a document.

Comment: @Nelles, I want to update the documents with set of 10 fields where status field should be updated if the value is not 'COMPLETED' or else leave as it is.